# Read a json string using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

How can i read this json string using a loop, the intention is to create/append a table with 3 columns containing in each row one of this json values, not sure how can i achieve it

```
{
"1":
  {
    "update":"Ja existe",
    "numero":1,
    "registro":"IBRAM - 2014"
  },
"2":
  {
    "update":"Ja existe",
    "numero":2,
    "registro":"PM-SP - 2014"
  },
"3":
  {
    "update":"Ja existe",
    "numero":3,
    "registro":"ARTESP - 2014"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a string, then you can convert it to a JSON object and iterate through each element  as follows:

```
var json = JSON.parse('THE JSON STRING');
for (key in json) {
  var value = json[key];
  // do whatever you wanna do with the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for in` and loop on it

```
var myjson = $.parseJSON('< the json string>');

    for (key in myjson ) {

        var myitem = myjson[key];
        alert(myitem.update);

    }
```

but if in your code above its not a json string its already serialize in json ready to be iterated. see this http://jsfiddle.net/725cev7s/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Not sure how i can acess the elements inside the json, yes its a string

Comment: you need to parse it into a JSON object by using `$.parseJSON()` then you can iterate on it using `for in`

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON string & then for loop for retrieve value. Try something like below

```
<script>
var data = '{"1":{"update":"Ja existe","numero":1,"registro":"IBRAM - 2014"},"2":{"update":"Ja existe","numero":2,"registro":"PM-SP - 2014"},"3":{"update":"Ja existe","numero":3,"registro":"ARTESP - 2014"}}';
var json = JSON.parse(data);
for (var key in json) {
    var value = json[key];
    console.log(value.update);
    console.log(value.numero);
    console.log(value.registro);
}
</script>
```